# how to open particular fragment which in an activity when notification is clicked

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I have a notification in notification bar and I have 3 fragments in one of my activity. 
When I click the notification, I want that it will open particular fragment, Like what facebook notification do. I tried to search it on google and everywhere else but didn't found what I need.

Example: I have 3 fragments

> 1. for redeem value.
> 2. for recharge.
> 3. for anything.

Now if i get notification from Admin Panel like you can redeem your value, then that notification will open that particular fragment. If i get notification to recharge then it will open that particular fragment, like this i want it working.

Hope you are clear, if not then please let me know.

Comment: What's the problem? Just open your activity and add whichever fragment you want to the activity.

Comment: but it is not working while launching app. In service class there is startId variable other than this main activity, remaining having value as 1. for this homeactivity the startId is 2. How to clear the stack values

Comment: Could you be a little more clear. Post relevant code and the error which are occurring.

Comment: how to cancel current activity's fragment? I am using FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT but, It is not working

Comment: newly launched app is working with notification perfectly but, already existed app not responding correctly with notification

Comment: To remove the current fragment you can pop that fragment from the stack - `getFragmentManager().popBackStack();` or `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove()` depending on your condition and then you can add the new one.

Comment: I finally got the result with intent and pending intent flags. And thanks for ur replys

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do it

```
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);    

Intent resultIntent = null;

resultIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context.getApplicationContext()); 

        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);

        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

Further you can set your param's accordingly

Comment: if(category.equalsIgnoreCase("Tips")){
   intent = new Intent(this, TipsFeedActivity.class);
  }else if(category.equalsIgnoreCase("Album") || category.equalsIgnoreCase("EventAdd") || category.equalsIgnoreCase("EventJoin") || category.equalsIgnoreCase("EventExcuse") || category.equalsIgnoreCase("FeedWall")){
   intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
  }else if(category.equalsIgnoreCase("GuestJoin")){
   intent = new Intent(this, GuestJoinWeddingActivity.class);
  }else {
   intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
  }

Comment: this is the gcmIntentservice class

Comment: How can I set My param's accordingly bcz, I am very new to this subject plz help me

Comment: newly launched app is working with notification perfectly but, already existed app not responding correctly with notification